# Keep opened files between close and reopen

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I open some single file (without creating any project), and then close and reopen VS Code, the file will be restored. Okay, that's what I want.

But, if I open some file, then close VS Code, and then open another single file, the first file will not be reopened.

Is there way to fix it? Probably, some changes in "User Settings" (?).

I've already tried

```json
"window.restoreWindows": "all"
```

but it doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: This is possible since version 1.52 November 2020 - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67828630/68939).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new setting `preserve` for `window.restoreWindows` [has been introduced](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52#_restore-previous-session-windows)  ([#15949](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15949)) in version 1.52 November 2020. This should do just what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the same issue as described in the following feature request:

[Keep previously opened files when opening a single file instead of clearing all files (#14675)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14675)

Which means that no, this is not possible at the moment.

Comment: This is possible since version 1.52 November 2020 - see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844270/keep-opened-files-between-close-and-reopen/67828630#67828630).

Answer (score 0):

Go to
Settings > Window > In Restore Windows section set it to > all

That's it. There are other options you can find your best.

I am using [visual studio code Version 1.27](https://code.visualstudio.com/) on linux.

Comment: That setting was already mentioned in the question, the problem is that it only works within workspaces / when a folder is opened.