# Open with VSCode from right click in Windows Explorer, did't reopen the previous files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Description:

When i open a selected file from windows explorer using right click menu with "Open with VS Code", VSCode only open the file i selsected. It did't reopen the previous files like sublime.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

already set "window.restoreWindows": "all"

OS: Windows 10 1803
VSCode 1.24.0

Comment: There may be other ways of doing this, but on my Mac, I has an alias that opens multiple documents at once from the Terminal.. eg:  code -n ~/.profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile - So you can do things like this from a command line. On my Mac, VS Code always reopens last project and all documents I had opened before. Following on from this it may be possible to do things like code dirname in the parent directory.. Just a thought. BTW: Not sure on Windows if its' the same - but if you type code in the view > command palette - it gives you option to install code as a command.

Comment: It looks like this was mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34529). It seems it's not part of their current development roadmap so I'm not sure if there's a way to make it behave the way you're expecting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open file in new tab in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705543/how-to-open-file-in-new-tab-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844270/keep-opened-files-between-close-and-reopen/67828630#67828630