# Visual Studio Code - How to open files in new tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

I searched for the answer, but all of questions I found concerned opening new files from within VS Code.

I would like VS Code to remember the files I had open before I closed it, but when VS Code is not running and I open a file using context menu "Open with Code", it forgets the files I had in tabs, leaving only the new file, but if VS Code is already running and I open a new file the same way, it is being added as a new tab leaving previous files in tabs intact.

In other words:

1. I have few files open in VS Code.
2. I close the application.
3. Next time I start it:

   a) by launching it with shortcut - it remembers the files, (GOOD)

   b) by opening some file - it forgets old files, leaving only the new file open. (BAD)

Is it possible to always add new files as new tabs, like in Sublime Text or Notepad++?

Best regards

Comment: Someone asked [the exact same question a few hours before you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889658/open-with-vscode-from-right-click-in-windows-explorer-didt-reopen-the-previous).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry I didn't find it before posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open file in new tab in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705543/how-to-open-file-in-new-tab-in-visual-studio-code)