# Reopen last closed tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Studio Code. I've been tinkering with the settings for a while now and haven't yet found a way to make VSCode **automatically** reopen last closed tab(s). Say, I opened *file 1*, closed VSCode, went to open *file 2* (in a separate folder), just to end up with only one tab opened despite what I have in my settings.json file:

```
 "files.hotExit": "onExit",
 "window.reopenFolders": "all",
 "window.restoreWindows": "all"
```

I don't mind accumulated tabs every time I open VSCode, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> exists for a reason); if Notepad++ and Sublime Text can do it, then why not VSCode? Or am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844270/keep-opened-files-between-close-and-reopen/67828630#67828630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code can currently only open one workspace in one window. Unless you have manually specified a [multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces), VS Code will always open new files and folders as separate workspaces.